# build matrix in a for loop automatically in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a code like this

```
probv=c(0.5,0.1,0.2,0.3)
N=c(1,2,3,4)

g1=matrix(rbinom(n = 10, size = N[1], prob = probv[1]), nrow=5)
g2=matrix(rbinom(n = 10, size = N[2], prob = probv[2]), nrow=5)
g3=matrix(rbinom(n = 10, size = N[3], prob = probv[3]), nrow=5)
g4=matrix(rbinom(n = 10, size = N[4], prob = probv[4]), nrow=5)
```

I want to use a for loop
for i in (1:J)
{......} J=4 in this case
use one line function to return the same output like this, I want to know
how I create a matrix g_ in the loop
which is also benefit for me when I increase the length
of my vector into 5,6,7......
for example N=c(1,2,3,4,5) probv=c(0.5,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5)
I do not change my code to create another matrix called g5.The code can create it and I just need to change my input to achieve my goal

Thanks Akrun

what is my N is a three dimensional array, I want to map the last dimension of it? How to change in the map method?

```
probv=c(0.5,0.1,0.2,0.3)
N=array(1:24,c(3,2,4))

g1=matrix(rbinom(n = 10, size = N[,,1], prob = probv[1]), nrow=5)
g2=matrix(rbinom(n = 10, size = N[,,2], prob = probv[2]), nrow=5)
g3=matrix(rbinom(n = 10, size = N[,,3], prob = probv[3]), nrow=5)
g4=matrix(rbinom(n = 10, size = N[,,4], prob = probv[4]), nrow=5)
```

Comment: Here, the lengths of 'probv' is 5 and last dimension of N is 4

Comment: thanks, the first method is cool, and the second method looks like just produce 1 2by20 matrix

Comment: `lst2` is a `list` of matrices (5 x 2) and the length of the list is 4.  When we `rbind`, we get the 20 x2 because we are rbinding the list elements.  I was not sure whether you need a single matrix of a list of matrices

Comment: sorry I need a list of matrices with g1,g2,g3,g4

Comment: updated by assigning names to the list elements so that you can get the list elements by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map` to loop over the 'N' and 'probv' `vector`, get the corresponding values into `rbinom` and create a `matrix`.  It returns a `list` of `matric`es

```
lst1 <- Map(function(x, y) matrix(rbinom(n = 10,
        size = x, prob = y), nrow = 5), N, probv)
```

---

Or using `for` loop

```
lst2 <- vector('list', length(N))
for(i in seq_along(N)) {
     lst2[[i]] <- matrix(rbinom(n = 10, size = N[i], prob = probv[i]), nrow = 5)
   }
 names(lst2) <- paste0("g", seq_along(lst2))
```

For the updated question to extract from an `array`

```
mnLength <- min(length(probv), dim(N)[3])
lst2 <- vector('list', mnLength)
for(i in seq_len(mnLength)) {
     lst2[[i]] <- matrix(rbinom(n = 10, size = N[,,i], prob = probv[i]), nrow = 5)
   }

names(lst2) <- paste0("g", seq_along(lst2))
lst2$g1
lst2$g2
```

Comment: thanks what if my N is an array and I want to map the last dimension of it.

Comment: ```probv=c(0.5,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5)
N=array(1:24,c(3,2,4))

g1=matrix(rbinom(n = 10, size = N[,,1], prob = probv[1]), nrow=5)
g2=matrix(rbinom(n = 10, size = N[,,2], prob = probv[2]), nrow=5)
g3=matrix(rbinom(n = 10, size = N[,,3], prob = probv[3]), nrow=5)
g4=matrix(rbinom(n = 10, size = N[,,4], prob = probv[4]), nrow=5)

Comment: For  the second method, could you change it to produce 4 matrices ,instead of 1 matrix?thanks

Comment: @hardworker For the second, just use `lst2`.  It is a `list` of 4 matrices.   you don't need to `rbind` it to create `mat1`.  Or convert to an array if you want an array